# Dynamic photo gallery using ECMAScript

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to create a **photo gallery slide show web part** and it should be dynamic.

I created a picture library called "photo gallery".

I want this picture library to be displayed as a slide show. Latest pictures should come first.

Without using **picture library slide show web part** how can we implement this using ECMA script or JavaScript?

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getImages,"sp.js")

Function getImages (){
  var ctx=SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web=ctx.get_web();
  var list=web.get_lists().getByTitle("myImageLibrary")
  var query=new SP.CamlQuery();
  var queryXml="<View><Query><Orderby><FieldRef Name='Created' /></Orderby></Query></View>";
  query.set_viewXml(queryXml);
  this.listItems=list.get items(query)
  ctx.load(listItems)
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.create delegate(this,onSuccess), Function.create delegate(this,onFail))

}
Function onSuccess (){
  var listEnum=listItems.getEnumerator()
  while(listEnum.moveNext()){
      var item=listEnum.get_current()
      var URL=item.get_url()
      $("selector").append("<IMG SRC='"+URL+"/>";
}
// use any jquery slideshow for this
$("selector").slideshow();
}
Function onFail(){}
```

You get the point there are a lot of options here...